# Android Studio: "Cannot resolve symbol" registering service in manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-service

This is my first android project, I use Android Studio 0.5.2
I am trying to build a live wallpaper and found this neat tutorial:
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/a-bare-bones-live-wallpaper-template-for-android/

I followed it and everything seems fine except the registration of the WallpaperService in the manifest.

```
 <service
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="Battery Wallpaper"
        android:name=".DemoWallpaperService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER"
        >
```

where the name is defined, i get "Cannot resolve symbol '.DemoWallpaperService' "

i tried adding the package name but it didn't help either.
I also checked, DemoWallpaperService does import and extend WallpaperService without error

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a class like `<app_package_name>.DemoWallpaperService`?

Comment: yes, i have. It is exactly the one from the tutorial but I'll post the whole source code  http://pastebin.com/taVbx6J1

Comment: Is that the whole source code? I can't see there the java `package` statement at the very first line.

Comment: Oh yes, it was missing the package statement. I am new to android studio and got confused by the UI. I didn't know how to add the java file, so i added a class, apparently it was not put into my package, but i refractored it and now it is inside my package (from the UI' perspective at least) and i added the package statement. Thank you! Now all i get is "top level element is not completed"   i don't know exactly what it means, but the app is working now

Comment: So can I add that as an answer?

Comment: yes, my problem is solved. My class was not in the package and was missing the package statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All java files must begin with the `package` statement, but I can not see it from code you posted in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/taVbx6J1).

Add to your class' first line:

```
package <app_package_name>;
```

And in your project, make sure there is a DemoWallpaperService.java file within the  folder.

Answer (score 1):

The directory structure of your java files MUST be :

```
[project]\[module]\src\main\java\[yourpackage]\[yourclass.java]
```